# How to check max count of lines of a js file with ESLint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I've read all the rules provided by [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/), but I can't find how to check max count of lines of a js file.

Say, I want to limit js files from having more than 100 lines.

Does ESLint provide this feature? how can I do it with ESLint?

Comment: @Jason Marsh, thanks for editing my grammar errors

Answer (score 2):

As I know in `ESLint` there is no options to check count of lines, but there is npm package [`eslint-rules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-rules) where there is option [`no-long-files`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-rules#no-long-files) you can try use it.